# when combo box value changed, display a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to know how to display a textbox when I selected other values in combobox.

For example when I changed the value of the combobox from Cash to Bank, it will  display a textbox, same goes to others.

Comment: To clarify: when you select an option in a `<select>` drop down, you want a text box to appear that modifies the value of the given selected value?

Comment: @bokonic, nope, just a blank textbox would do.

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done bins for above issue using java script on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpa0

**HTML:**

```
<select id="ChoiceMaker" name="ChoiceMaker">
  <option value="">
    Please choose
  </option>
  <option value="cash">
    Cash
  </option>
  <option value="bank">
    Bank
  </option>
</select>
<div id="cashContainer">
  Cash: 
  <input type="text" id="cash"/>
</div>
<div id="bankContainer">
  Bank: 
  <input type="text" id="cash"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cashContainer {
  display:none;
}
#bankContainer{
  display:none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var choice_combo = document.getElementById('ChoiceMaker');
choice_combo.onchange = function() {
    switch (this.value.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'cash':
        document.getElementById("bankContainer").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("cashContainer").style.display = 'block';
        break;
    case 'bank':
        document.getElementById("cashContainer").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("bankContainer").style.display = 'block';
        break;

    }
}
```

DEMO: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpa0

Comment: Weird, I tried modify your coding and try putting it on head, it doesn't work?

Comment: I like your coding due to easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
$('select#yourID').change(function(){
    $('#textboxID').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val()
  switch (val) {
    case 'Cash':
      $('#cash').show()
      break
    case 'Bank':
      $('#bank').show()
      break
    ...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

And another version using selectedIndex

**JQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    // Set initial state
    $("#cashContainer").hide();
    $("#bankContainer").hide();

    // How it all works
    $("#ChoiceMaker").change(function () {
      $value = $("#ChoiceMaker")[0].selectedIndex;
      // You can also use $("#ChoiceMaker").val(); and change the case 0,1,2: to the values of the html select options elements

      switch ($value)
      {
        case 0:
          $("#cashContainer").hide();
          $("#bankContainer").hide();
          alert("Please make a choice");
          break;
        case 1:
          $("#cashContainer").show();
          $("#bankContainer").hide();
          break;
        case 2:
          $("#cashContainer").hide();
          $("#bankContainer").show();
          break;
      }


    });

  });
```

**HTML**

```
    <select id="ChoiceMaker" name="ChoiceMaker">
            <option value="">Please choose</option>
            <option value="cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="bank">Bank</option>
    </select>
    <div id="cashContainer">Cash: <input type="text" id="cash"/></div>
    <div id="bankContainer">Bank: <input type="text" id="cash"/></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put a text box in a table and give an id for the table.
Then in the onitemchange event call a function. Inside the function write:

```
document.getelementById("tableid").display="none";// for hiding
document.getelementById("tableid").display="block";// for showing
```

You can also do this using jQuery.

Comment: Why put the text box in a table? Why not use the text box's ID?

Comment: could u please explain how to do that using plain java script @Jon P